# Is there a way to disable a marker or a polygon to be draggable in leaflet-geoman?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, cartography, leaflet-geoman

As the title says, I have a set of different markers and polygons on a map.
All I want to do is to disable the markers and the polygons I create on the map to be dragged and only make circles draggable.
As far as I read the documentation, there's no way to do that in drag mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, there is no way to disable the drag.

But you can use this workaround:

```
function enableDrag(){
    map.eachLayer((layer)=>{
        if(layer._dragDisabled){
            layer._pmTempLayer = false;
            layer._dragDisabled = false;
        }
    });
}

function disableDrag(){
    map.eachLayer((layer)=>{
        if(layer instanceof L.Circle){
            layer._pmTempLayer = true;
            layer._dragDisabled = true;
        }
    });
}
```

When a layer has the property `_pmTempLayer` it is filtered out in the drag function.

Comment: Adding layer._pmTempLayer = true and layer._dragDisabled = true while I'm adding specific markers and polygons seems to be a good option, thanks!